# Saving a Word File from Mailmerge with Data Base Field Name as the File Name

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I would like to able to save the active file in Word 2010 MailMerge, with its file name derived from the database field "First_Name" and from the database Field "Last_Name" into a subfolder that is a hardcoded subfolder.

I receive an error that the `"requested member of the collection does not exist"`.

I know this error occurs when you try to access an object that does not exist. The data base field is First_Name, and I have tried First Name as well in case the code was searching for the Address Field of First Name, which has been paired with the Data Base Field of First_Name.
Here is what I have tried:

```
Sub SavingIndividuallyByCustomerName()

Dim firstname As String
Dim lastname As String

firstname = ActiveDocument.FormFields("First_Name").Result
lastname = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Last_Name").Result

    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
        .LastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
    End With
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\folder\subfolder\subsubfolder\"


 ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
        "C:\folder\subfolder\subsubfolder\" & firstname & lastname & ".docx"
End Sub
```

When I hardcoded the name with

```
firstname = "John"
lastname = "Doe"
```

I had no other errors and the active file saved.

I also attempted to use without success:

```
Dim firstname As Field
Dim lastname As Field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
firstname = ActiveDocument.FormFields("First_Name").Result

lastname = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Last_Name").Result
```

you need

```
firstname = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("First_Name").Value

lastname = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Last_Name").Value
```

The name in quotes is case-sensitive (unusual in Windows programming). It has to match the name that Word is actually using, which may not be identical to the one in the data source.